# Problem with getting objects based on ManyToManyField relation

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have Meal model and Ingredient, Meal have ManyToMany relation to Ingredient.
I try to get objects that match by Ingredients
**models.py**

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    recipe = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    difficulty = ForeignKey('Difficulty', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    ingridients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingridient')
    ico = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

class CategoryIngridients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingridient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    category = ForeignKey('CategoryIngridients', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    difficulty = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    #ingridients = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = "__all__"

class IngrigientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Ingridient
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class TestCraft(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ingridients_tmp = request.data['ingredients']
        ingrid = Ingridient.objects.filter(id__in=ingridients_tmp)
        print(ingrid)
        queryset = Meal.objects.filter(ingridients__in=ingrid)
        print(queryset)
        serializer = MealSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I POST json:

```
{"ingredients":[1,2]}
```

This view return, but they are repeating:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "difficulty": "Medium",
        "user": "vleo",
        "name": "gfgd",
        "description": "",
        "recipe": "...",
        "is_published": true,
        "ico": "",
        "ingridients": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "user": "vleo",
        "name": "залупа",
        "description": "[eqyz",
        "recipe": "n.,sr",
        "is_published": false,
        "ico": "",
        "ingridients": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "difficulty": "Medium",
        "user": "vleo",
        "name": "gfgd",
        "description": "",
        "recipe": "...",
        "is_published": true,
        "ico": "",
        "ingridients": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "user": "vleo",
        "name": "sdf",
        "description": "[eqyz",
        "recipe": "n.,sr",
        "is_published": false,
        "ico": "",
        "ingridients": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

Also can you advise: How do i make *class TestCraft(APIView)*, so by one path i can use ingredients from json and also retrive meals(queryset) using axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a query with filter on many-to-many field,  entries can appear repetedly in the result. Just change to

```
queryset = Meal.objects.filter(ingridients__in=ingrid).distinct()
```

to remove multible entries with .distinct()